# WPF AutoCompleteBox

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit

Does anybody know how to change the Background of the selected item in the drop down list of the AutoCompleteBox?

Comment: Did you try anything by yourself or do you expect us to deliver the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to set the background of the selected item you just have to override the `SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey`

```
<sdk:AutoCompleteBox>
     <sdk:AutoCompleteBox.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Red"/>
    </sdk:AutoCompleteBox.Resources>
</sdk:AutoCompleteBox>
```

Comment: I want to change the background of the selected item in this list. I know I can copy the control template and edit it. I was just thinking there is an easier way to achieve this.

Comment: ahhh.. Try my edit above, I can't test right now, but it should work :)

Comment: Thank you very much. It is working correctly with ControlBrushKey.